# Reference multiple var defined within class via classmethod

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to reference multiple vars defined within a class by classmethod (or by some other means)?

For context I'm trying to consolidate the CRUD and model classes for a SQL database to simplify the codebase.

For example I'm looking to implement something like the below:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Person:
      name: str
      gender: str
      age: int
    
      @classmethod
      def get_person(cls, db: Session) -> list[Person]:
         return db.query(cls.Person) # <-- Key part is here. I'll need to send name,
                                     #     gender, and age to the database. Currently 
                                     #     this is implemented separately as
                                     #    `class CrudPerson` and `class ModelPerson`.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `from __future__ import annotations` and referencing the class directly seems to work. (e.g. `db.query(Person)`)

Additional information on this can be found in [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)

Answer (score 0):

If you make `Person` a [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), you can use [`cls._fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields).

Or if you make `Person` a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), you can use [`dataclasses.fields(cls)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields).